# How to get the ISO Code of currency?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a requirement where I need to display the currency along with price, but the issue is that in my org i have enabled multi currencies, so I want to get the ISO code for that particular record.

For example, I have a order say 'A' whose product price is $20, I have another order say 'B' whose product price is GBP 10. I want to display this info on a Visual force page where the currency will depend on order type. Can anyone help me how to get the ISO code using query for a particular field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{!object.CurrencyISOCode} will give you the ISO code for that record.

I believe you can use {!Label[object.CurrencyISOCode]} to get the symbol, but I'm not 100% sure. That could always be done in a case formula once you have the ISO Code.

---

**edit**

I haven't tested this but something along these lines this should work if you have to include ISO Code in a query.

```
Object__c obj = [SELECT Whatever__c FROM Object__c WHERE Id = :someid];
String currencyCode = obj.get("CurrencyIsoCode");
```

Also... a bit ugly, but you can build a formula field (text) on the object "CurrencyIsoCode" and then it should behave just like any other field in queries, page layout, etc.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use the above thing but its not working. Can you please post the query so that I can learn.

I wrote the query as 
 String str=(String)[select isocode from currencytype where isocode=orderitem.CurrencyISOCode limit 1];
   
    is this right?

Comment: Firstly I want the to query the ISO code using Apex then display it

Comment: updated my answer. good luck...